# Hide external modules when importing a module (e.g. regarding code-completion)

Tags: python, code-completion, python-import

I have several modules in one package (a kind of a toolkit), which I use in my projects. The structure looks like this:

```
the_toolkit:
    __init__.py
    basic_io.py
    simple_math.py
    matrix_kit.py
    ...
```

Now when I use `IPython` or the code completion in `VIM` after importing a module from the package with

```
from the_toolkit import matrix_kit
```

I get a bunch of modules/functions which `matrix_kit.py` imports (`array`, `math`, `log`, `loggin`, `format_exc`, etc.), along with the actual functions which `matrix_kit` defines.
How can I filter out everything else, since I'm not interested in `math` or `array` in a code completion of the `matrix_kit` module?

The `__init__.py` is empty as suggested by many pythonistas, or is it the way to do it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19757025/1834164 which explains how `__all__' can be used to hide modules also in ipython.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had the same problem, and solved it by adding a leading underscore to all my imports. It doesn't look brilliant, but it achieves what you're after.

```py
from __future__ import division as _division
import numpy as _np
import pandas as _pd
```

Only the stuff that starts without an underscore is imported when you import the module using from .. import *. or when you use tab-completion in IPython or spyder.

Comment: This is the only solution that I found to work. Thank you. Btw, you should note that the underscore is added to the imports inside your modules, which you later import as packages. It is a bit confusing now.

Answer (score 17):

I've come to like and use this approach. Starting with your project structure, we will hide all the content of `matrix_kit` that you don't want to show.

```
the_toolkit:
    __init__.py
    basic_io.py
    simple_math.py
    matrix_kit.py
    ...
```

Move `matrix_kit.py` into a package with the same name, and place one underscore in the beginning of the module's name:

```
the_toolkit:
    __init__.py
    basic_io.py
    simple_math.py
    matrix_kit:
        __init__.py
        _matrix_kit.py
    ...
```

Now in `_matrix_kit.py` add a global variable `__all__ = [...]` listing the names of all functions/classes/variables you want to be visible. Then, add the following line to `matrix_kit/__init__.py`:

```
from ._matrix_kit import *
```

It will only import the stuff listed in the `__all__` attribute of the module. Then, while importing `matrix_kit` like you've done before, you will actually import the `__init__.py` and its content.

Comment: This solved a problem I have been having for a while, thank you! Any idea if this is a "typical" way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: @Engineero yes, I've seen it used in a lot of projects.

Comment: I have searched for many hours trying to find an answer like this. Thank you so much. What I really like about this approach is how compartmentalised the API looks when using tab completion. I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution I came up with is to implement a short API class in the `__init__` file which can make use of the `__all__` variable (which may already be defined for `import *` purposes). Something like this in `__init__.py`:

```
import matrix_kit

class _matrix_kit_API:
    def __init__(self):
        for func in matrix_kit.__all__:
            setattr(self, func, eval(f"matrix_kit.{func}"))

matrix_kit = _matrix_kit_API()
```

Answer (score -2):

you may get some mileage out of [`__all__`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)

Comment: Could you be more specific? Should I add `__all__` to all my modules within the package and list the functions which are important? (*import*ant, haha)

Comment: @second: did you try defining `__all__` in a module then import the module (not doing a star import) in IPython ?

Comment: I do not use the `*` and I tried adding `__all__` in a module, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @septi: defining `__all__` is a good practice, but it won't help wrt/ your completion problem - the imported names are still accessible from the module's dict, and as such can be used by the completer's code. IOW, the problem is with your autocompleters implementation (that does not filter out imported names), not with Python itself.

Comment: `__all__` won't work here, as it is used to specify which module files are to be imported when the `from *` statement is used.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: BTW, IPython *can* respect `__all__` in autocompletion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19757025/1447225