# Hide imported modules to interpreter

Tags: python, ipython

I have built a module which is using a few different modules for various tasks. When I'm importing my module in IPython and listing the available functions for autocompletion, these external modules are included in that list. Is it possible to hide them in some way?

Comment: AFAIK no, but I'm no IPython expert. An ugly workaround that works is to create a new module where you import *what you want* from the module you mention and then use this new module instead of the other one. Yet an other workaround is to rename the `import`s. For example if you use `moduleA` as helper, do `import moduleA as _moduleA`. Then autocompletion will be a problem only if you are trying to access an attribute that starts with `_`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python, modules can define an `__all__` variable, which is a list of the names that should be imported when someone does:

```
from module import *
```

IPython can use the same variable to limit completions, though it does not do this by default.  To enable this at runtime, set:

```
get_ipython().Completer.limit_to__all__ = True
```

Or to set it permanently, add to your `ipython_config.py`:

```
c.IPCompleter.limit_to__all__ = True
```

Comment: Thanks for answering such an old question (by internet standards)!

Comment: Why doesn't IPython do this by default? Just curious - I'd bet there's a good reason and am curious to know.

Comment: Mainly because `__all__` is often not maintained very well, and unlike `_`-prefixed private members (hidden by default), there's no clear way to ask for the missing items without relaunching with changed config. You can see the patch [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/1529) and further discussion [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/1497).