# How can I hide a "utils" inside a submodule in python (vscode)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module

I have the following package structure:

```
package/:
    mymodule.py
    submodule/
        __init__.py
        utils.py
```

Contents of utils.py:

```
def double(arr):
    return arr * 2
```

Contents of __init__.py:

```
from utils import double
```

Now, in VSCode (don't know if it is a feature of vscode), how can I hide (or even make unavailable) the script "utils.py" from submodule? So that this doesn't happen (utils appearing):

[image]

I wanted to be able to just get access (or view) of the double function.

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509012/hide-external-modules-when-importing-a-module-e-g-regarding-code-completion) and see if renaming `utils.py` to `_utils.py` fix it.

Comment: It doesn't fix it. Unfortunately.

Comment: @Rodolfo I submitted the relevant request in GitHub for you, but it was rejected. It seems that they hope you can make it yourself. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/19167

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most efficient way is to set `"editor.suggest.showModules": false` Add this setting to your `settings.json` file.

For more VS Code intellisense settings you can check [this link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense)

Comment: Ye. But I want this specific module to be hidden, not all (if I add them).

Comment: I'm sorry, because the intellisense of the code doesn't do the hiding of specific modules. If you want to do that, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663958/hide-imported-modules-to-interpreter)might help you.

Comment: Bad solution, because module exists in dict of parent module.