# How to define the imports from a module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a directory structure like this:

```
└── stuff
    ├── __init__.py
    └── substuff
        ├── imp.py
        └── __init__.py
```

`stuff/__init__.py` looks as follows:

```
from stuff.substuff.imp import foo, bar
```

and `stuff/substuff/__init__.py` like this:

```
from stuff.substuff.imp import foo, bar

__all__ = [
    'foo',
    'bar'
]
```

`stuff/substuff/imp.py` contains

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

__all__ = ['foo', 'bar']


def foo():
    return {'foo': np.sqrt(2)}


def bar():
    return ('bar', 'xyz')


def _helper():
    return True
```

If I now do

```
from stuff.substuff import imp
```

and check what is available for `imp`, I see `bar`, `foo`, but also `pd` and `np`.

How can I achieve that the user only sees `bar` and `foo`, but not `pd` and `np`? One solution seems to be to import them as `_pd` and `_np`, but I am wondering whether there is a "prettier" solution than this.

Comment: Check this already answered question -  you should find your answer here along with a lot of ways in which you can go about achieving what you want to.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509012/hide-external-modules-when-importing-a-module-e-g-regarding-code-completion)

Comment: @shreyashag: This one I indeed missed when I googled; the first answer uses the underscores which I would like to avoid, the second one, seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that `__all__` doesn’t prevent any of the module symbols (functions, classes, etc.) from being directly imported. Check this amazing [article](http://xion.io/post/code/python-all-wild-imports.html) for more details. It only sets behavior for `from stuff.substuff.imp import *`, not explicit module import ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)).

This statement will only import `foo` and `bar` as you expect:

```
from stuff.substuff import *
```

Also you've already limited imports directly from `substuff` package to `foo` and `bar`:

```
from stuff.substuff import foo  # successfully imported
from stuff.substuff import pd  # import error
```

Comment: Yes, but it does not solve the issue with `from stuff.substuff import imp` where `pd` is still present.

Comment: Do you need to restrict such imports at all or import only useful stuff by default?

Comment: The user should only see what is defined in `__all__`; that `__all__` is only used when we have the wildcard import was known to me, I was just wondering how to restrict it to this.

Comment: Then you can let the user import directly from `substuff` package (only what you explicitly imported to `__init__` from inner modules). Does this approach work for you? Of course, the user still can import submodules directly but I believe you can't prevent this in "elegant" way.

Comment: I think the link from above shows nicely how to do it; I would certainly like to prevent it to protect myself and the user from doing something funny ;) Upvoted now.