# Avoid sequential import

Tags: python, namespaces, python-import

I am trying to make a custom module, where modules as `numpy`, `scipy`, etc. are imported. I am facing a problem of "deep" sequential import. I see that it is a general behaviour:

```
import numpy
print(numpy.sys)
```

Does not provide error (so I can access `sys` through `numpy` which is quite weird in my opinion). Can I avoid this somehow in my own package?

Comment: Why is this behaviour a problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509012/hide-external-modules-when-importing-a-module-e-g-regarding-code-completion