# Passing attributes and methods of object inside another object

Tags: python, object, composition

I am writing an API in Python 3.9. I'll first provide a simplified example of what I'm working on and below the code will expand a bit on what I'm trying to implement from a design perspective. I just started getting into more complex design and object composition things, so it's entirely possible that some of what I'm trying to do is either not possible or not best practice - I'd be interested to know what I can improve.

In `primary_module.py`:

```
from some_module import do_something
from secondary_module import SecondaryClass

class PrimaryClass:
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.attr1 = param1
        self._attr2 = do_something(param2)
    def primary_method(self):
        sec_cls = SecondaryClass(PrimaryClass)
        sec_cls.secondary_method()
```

In `secondary_module.py`:

```
class SecondaryClass:
    def secondary_method(pri_cls):
        print(pri_cls.attr1)
        print(pri_cls._attr2)
```

As you can see, I have one class `SecondaryClass` defined in `secondary_module.py` and am using that to compose a class called `PrimaryClass` in `primary_module.py`. From an API standpoint, I would like end users to only directly access `PrimaryClass` and never let them see `SecondaryClass` even though it is being used under the hood. The only time `SecondaryClass` needs to be instantiated is when running `PrimaryClass.primary_method()` and related objects, so there's no situation in which `SecondaryClass` would run as a standalone object. However, when running this method, `SecondaryClass` needs access to some of the user-specified data contained in `PrimaryClass`. Keeping in mind that `SecondaryClass` is (theoretically) never directly accessed by end users, what's the best way to allow `SecondaryClass` to see certain attributes of `PrimaryClass`? Is it acceptable to use duck typing in the definition of `SecondaryClass.secondary_method()` to grant it access to certain attributes (both public and hidden) of `PrimaryClass`? Or is there some better solution that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Private methods can't be accessed from outside the class. That's what makes them "private".

Comment: You need an argument to `secondary_method`: `sec_cls.secondary_method(self)`

Comment: Why are you passing `PrimaryClass` as the argument to the `SecondaryClass` constructor?

Comment: Ok the private method comment makes sense. I'll edit the question and code to remove those. For your last comment on passing ```PrimaryClass``` to the ```SecondaryClass``` constructor, the idea was to use duck typing rather than actually type enforcing a ```PrimaryClass``` object since I think that would lead to a circular dependency

Comment: You don't need to pass a class name to do duck typing. Just pass an instance.

Comment: Right, ```pri_cls``` could technically be anything. I intended it to mean an instance, which is why I truncated it and didn't refer to it as ```PrimaryClass```. I probably didn't write it the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not totally clear, but I think this is what you want:

```
class PrimaryClass:
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.attr1 = param1
        self._attr2 = do_something(param2)
    def primary_method(self):
        sec_cls = SecondaryClass(self)
        sec_cls.secondary_method()
    def __private_method(self):
        do_something_else()

class SecondaryClass:
    def __init__(self, primary):
        self.primary = primary

    def secondary_method():
        print(self.primary.attr1)
        print(self.primary._attr2)
```

To hide `SecondaryClass` from users of `primary_module`, use:

```
from secondary_module import SecondaryClass as _SecondaryClass
```

See [Hide external modules when importing a module (e.g. regarding code-completion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509012/hide-external-modules-when-importing-a-module-e-g-regarding-code-completion)

Comment: Thanks for this, but is there a way to keep ```SecondaryClass``` hidden from the end user? I think if an end user sees it, they would just be confused, and they shouldn't really have a reason to want to work directly with the ```SecondaryClass```. That's kind of why I had separated them to different modules.

Comment: How does the end user see it?

Comment: Do you mean they can refer to `primary_module.SecondaryClass` because it's imported by `primary_module.py`? Python doesn't provide a way to hide names from `import`.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. I thought I had read somewhere that certain modules can be hidden with a leading underscore in the filename, so I figured that was a good way to keep the more technical stuff hidden from the user. I didn't put the underscored filename in my question though.

Comment: You're right. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509012/hide-external-modules-when-importing-a-module-e-g-regarding-code-completion

Comment: Also FYI check the Python page on modules [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). It says in section 6.1 if you do ```from foo import *``` then all packages in ```foo``` _except_ those with leading underscores will be imported. So I might stick the underscore in the filename but other than that your answer holds. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to discuss this without understanding what the classes are actually doing.

That said, *it's generally not a good idea to have two classes mutually depending on each other* as this tends to generate brittle code: **changes in either class will potentially break both classes** and whoever depends on either of them.

It'd be better to pass `secondary_method` what it needs explicitly (i.e. `secondary_method(self._attr2)`), possibly as a function pointer (e.g. `lambda: __private_method()`, `lambda: self.attr1`), either through the class constructor (i.e. `__init__`) or as a method parameter for `secondary_method`. This way, `SecondaryClass` doesn't depend on `PrimaryClass` specifically and the dependencies from `secondary_method` and `SecondaryClass` are made explicit.

```py
class PrimaryClass:
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.attr1 = param1
        self._attr2 = do_something(param2)

    def primary_method(self):
        # E.g. 1: Pass _attr2 via constructor
        sec_cls = SecondaryClass(self._attr2)
        # E.g. 2+3: Pass attr1 and _attr2 as method parameters
        sec_cls.secondary_method(
            lambda: self.attr1,
            lambda: __private_method(),
        )

    def __private_method(self):
        do_something_else()

class SecondaryClass:
    def __init__(self, attr2):
        self.attr2 = attr2

    def secondary_method(get_attr1, private_callback):
        print(self.attr2)    # <- _attr2, received from constructor
        print(get_attr1())  # <- Getting attr1 at execution time from lambda
        private_callback()    # <- Calling __private_method
```

Comment: Thanks for the input and for pointing out these shortcomings. To give a bit more context, my ```PrimaryClass``` corresponds to a data structure that contains both experimental data and metadata. My ```SecondaryClass``` corresponds to a data exporter class. The idea is that I will have a few classes with a similar structure to ```PrimaryClass``` (i.e. different types of datasets with different assumptions about each), so the data exporter will use the properties of these classes to perform the formatting of file names and identify target directories, etc when the user wants to export data.